# Azure Flask-Restful Deploy Failure

Tags: python, azure, flask-restful

I'm trying to deploy a Flak Restful API to azure.
I have set up continuous deployment with a Github repo.

The deployment is failing on one of the requirements.txt

returning the following error:

```
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'azure-common ~=1.1.4', 'at', ' ~=1.1.4')
```

The application is running fine locally.
I'm new to the Azure platform and the config and deploy files are quite confusing I'm not sure if the problem is with these or the package in the virtual environment.

Comment: do you have requirements.txt in the root of your project? it is probably asking you to remove the space before `~=`

Comment: Yes requirements.txt is at the root. I thought that would be the issue but there is no space in requirements.txt: 'azure-common==1.1.4'

Answer (score 1):

You need to update pip, as I guess the version is old enough to do not support the "~=" syntax in the [setup.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-compute/setup.py#L66) of the packages you install.

For examples:

1. [ValueError "Expected version spec" when installing local wheel via pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502283/valueerror-expected-version-spec-when-installing-local-wheel-via-pip)
2. [How to fix error “Expected version spec in …” using pip install on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773883/how-to-fix-error-expected-version-spec-in-using-pip-install-on-windows)